# ExtJs PivotGrid without TopAxis aggregator

Tags: extjs, extjs6

With my current data structure i don't need a TopAxis at all, i only need to agroup the left axis

This is the data i'm getting from server:

```
{
 name:lorem,
 estab:impsom,
 depart:dolor,
 C:false,
 R:true,
 U:false,
 D:false
}
```

and this is my matrix:

```js
matrix: {
colGrandTotalsPosition: 'none',
textRowLabels: 'Depart',
viewLayoutType: 'compact',
store: 'myColabStore',
leftAxis: [{
        dataIndex: 'depart',
        header: 'depart'
    },
    {
        dataIndex: 'estab',
        header: 'estab'
    },
    {
        dataIndex: 'name',
        header: 'Name'
    }
]
aggregate: [{
        column: {
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            widget: {
                xtype: 'checkbox'
            }
        },
        dataIndex: 'R',
        header: 'Read'
    },
    {
        dataIndex: 'C',
        header: 'Create'
    },
    {
        dataIndex: 'U',
        header: 'Update'
    },
    {
        dataIndex: 'D',
        header: 'Delete'
    }
]
}
```

It seems without a top axis i can't render any data on grid, what should i do? how can i agroup only the leftaxis by estab and depart and still show the other data?

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't know if this is the right anwser but my workaround was to create a field in the model:

```
fields: [
 ...
{
    calculate: function(data) {
        return 'Permissions';
    },
    name: 'permis'
}
]
```

And in the matrix i just used:

```
matrix: [
    topAxis: [{
        dataIndex: 'permis'
    }]
]
```